# Implementing OOP Design Patterns in Jetpack Compose: Adapting Class-Based Structures to Functional Composables

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

As I continue to work with Jetpack Compose, I'm exploring ways to implement traditional OOP design patterns in this primarily functional environment. for example

```
interface TimelineComponent {
    @Composable
    fun Render()
}

class TimelineItem(
    private val id: String,
    private val type: String,
    private val title: String,
    private val subtitle: String
) : TimelineComponent {
    @Composable
    override fun Render() {
        Card(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                Text(text = "Title: $title\nType: $type\nSubtitle: $subtitle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code represents an attempt to use classes in a Composable context, specifically to demonstrate a design pattern in Jetpack Compose. However, I'm looking for insights on how to effectively implement OOP design patterns in a functional programming context like Jetpack Compose. What are the best practices for adapting traditional OOP patterns, such as Composite, in a system where the primary building blocks are functions?

Comment: i wonder if this question wouldn't be better on `softwareengineering.stackexchange.com` perhaps

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this while keeping in mind the example of composite recycler pattern. In my opinion it is one of the most powerful OOP patterns which is used in production.
Plenty of applications use this pattern to implement several screens. It seems to me like it can be implemented even easier in the context of Compose.

```
interface RecyclerItem {
    @Composable
    fun draw(modifier: Modifier)
}

class ImageItem(...) : RecyclerItem {
    @Composable
    override fun draw(modifier: Modifier) {...}
}

class TextItem(...) : RecyclerItem {
    @Composable
    override fun draw(modifier: Modifier) {...}
}
```

Then you can do something like this in few lines of code.

```
@Composable
fun CompositeRecycler(
    recyclerItems: List<RecyclerItem>,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    LazyColumn() {
        items(recyclerItems) { item ->
            item.draw(modifier)    
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example I can easily think of, while answering the question.